# How to get Authentication Token for Google Picasa in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, picasa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unauthorised access exception when Uploading photo to picasa in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634962/unauthorised-access-exception-when-uploading-photo-to-picasa-in-wp7)

I want to upload photos to picasa from WP7 phone app for which I want to get the authentication token in my code. I have posted my code in the post below

[Unauthorised access exception when Uploading photo to picasa in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634962/unauthorised-access-exception-when-uploading-photo-to-picasa-in-wp7)

the answer to the above post says to follow the steps mentioned in the below link

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Auth

But I m not using any google API. So is there any way to get the authentication token. Please let me know.

Comment: well, you probably need to authenticate with google services first. How familiar are you with OAuth?

Comment: @Alan - I provided a link to everything he needs, but he isn't doing it that way, so he is confused.

Answer (score 0):

> But I m not using any google API. So is there any way to get the
>   authentication token. Please let me know.

You need to use the Google API if you want to communicate with Picasa.  You need to use OAuth 1.0 in order to get the authentication token that is required to do what you want to do.

There a reason you started a new question to ask exactly the samething?

Comment: He should be using OAuth 2.0 per the linked articles.

Comment: I guess I need to port the Google API .NET source code to WP7 libraries. Please let me know if I can find the already ported dll somewhere.